# In django admin, an Inline admin, how to check if we are adding a new object or editing an existing one

Tags: django-admin

In an InlineAdmin I want to know, for example in `get_fields`, if we're adding a new entry or editing an existing one.

I want to show less fields during an addition, and more (all the) fields during an edit.

The 'obj' parameter refers to the primary object, and the relevant set (of the secondary objects) can be empty or not, but it does not directly translate to adding vs. editing.

Thanks in advance,
Oren